# The attachable property Triggers was not found in Style

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight-5.0

I have a  `RadTreeView` and trying to use stye triggers for disabling few nodes:

```
<telerikNavigation:RadTreeView  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HierarchyItemsTreeItemTemplate}">
    <telerikNavigation:RadTreeView.Style>
            <Style TargetType="telerikNavigation:RadTreeView">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=TreeViewItem}, Converter={StaticResource converter}}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="false"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </telerikNavigation:RadTreeView.Style>
</telerikNavigation:RadTreeView >
```

But this gives me error:

> The attachable property Triggers was not found in Style

Comment: are you build a windows 8 metro style app?

Comment: No, I am just using Win7 app

Comment: You should contact Telerik about this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You don't seem to specify the property your `Style` should apply to which is the `telerikNavigation:RadTreeView.Style`. As of now you got a `Style` as the `Content` of the `TreeView`

Try:

```
<telerikNavigation:RadTreeView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HierarchyItemsTreeItemTemplate}">
  <telerikNavigation:RadTreeView.Style>  <!-- Missing Line from original Code -->
    <Style TargetType="telerikNavigation:RadTreeView">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                                      AncestorType=TreeViewItem},
                                        Converter={StaticResource converter}}"
                      Value="true">
          <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                  Value="false" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </telerikNavigation:RadTreeView.Style>  <!-- Missing Line from original Code -->
</telerikNavigation:RadTreeView>
```

Comment: Was doing tthis, but dint update the question as the error persisted. Updated the question now, after updating also the error occurs

Comment: @Simsons, I have a similar issue in a Silverlight Project. Even try to style a textblock. The error is thrown.